# After July 2022 (version 1.70) release update option is missing in vs code settings button

Tags: visual-studio-code

After July 2022 (version 1.70) release, update option is **missing** in vs code settings button. How to update vscode.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean 'Check for Updates...' under Help menu?

Comment: Are you using Insiders edition? Mine is missing as well and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: I've reported this [on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157383)

Comment: That was marked as duplicate of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157624. I did not see a good argument for taking away the option for user type installs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This option is available on **`System Installer`** **not** <del>**`User Installer`**</del>. You can download it from [VS Code Download link](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)